# Custom UITableViewCell with AccessoryType breaks constraints

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to make a custom `UITableViewCell` with a label and an accessory type, but adding the accessory will cause some constraints to be broken.

This is my layout:

[image]

Without the accessory, nothing bad happens, and the log is clean.
When I add the accessory, the constraints between the labels and the Sync button are broken.

The elements are, however, laid out correctly, considering the width of the accessory view. This is the log from the console:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>       Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
>   (
>   
>   `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b90cbf270 H:|-(13)-[UILabel:0x7f9b90cbeb90'Top Label']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9b90cbe1c0 )>",
>   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b90cbf4f0 H:[UIButton:0x7f9b90cbd6c0'Sync']-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9b90cbe1c0 )>",
>   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b90cbf540 H:[UILabel:0x7f9b90cbeb90'Top Label']-(18)-[UIButton:0x7f9b90cbd6c0'Sync']>",
>   "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b90cc1550 'fittingSizeHTarget' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f9b90cbe1c0(38)]>"`
>   )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint
>   `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b90cbf540 H:[UILabel:0x7f9b90cbeb90'Top Label']-(18)-[UIButton:0x7f9b90cbd6c0'Sync']>`

What is the correct manner of using AutoLayout and an accessory view in the cell?

Comment: Have you tried removing the constraint between the labels and the Sync button? Unless you are trying to stretch the label because it has a colored background, you should not need this constraint. You have specified a width for the Sync button and labels have an intrinsic content size width based on the text they contain, so the width between the labels and Sync button need not be specified.

Comment: If you need the labels to stretch, set their content hugging priority lower than that of the Sync button.

Comment: I only set the background color to help to see the dimensions of the elements. Lowering the hugging priority did solve the problem, as long as I don't set `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` anymore. if I set the height, the bottom label (which should increase in height to accommodate the text) will no longer break the lines and will truncate the text.

Comment: I just noticed however, that when I click the cell, go the a second view controller and press Back, all the cells have their heights reset to 44

Comment: Increasing the compression resistance priority on the second label might help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why those log messages appear.
But I was able to fix the messages by stopping to set the accessory view on storyboard but writing code like `cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator`.